# Remove tuples from list that have duplicate key element

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm working on a reference implementing of a thinning mechanism comparable to that [duplicati](https://forum.duplicati.com/t/new-retention-policy-deletes-old-backups-in-a-smart-way/2195) that removes backups depending on age. Going back in time, it establishes a minimum time difference between backups in growing time frames. This algorithm is controlled by a *retention policy* written in a mini language `<frame1>:<limit1>,<frame2>:<limit2>,...,<frameN>:<limitN>`

For example, `"1D:3h,1W:1D,3M:1W"` means

- keep one backup every 3 hours for one day
- ... every day for one week
- ... every week for a 3 months
- remove all that are older

Due to the incremental process,<sup>[1]</sup> "programs" in this mini language can be "optimized":

- `"4W:2D,4W:1D"` into `"4W:2D"` applying rule #1 `x:a,x:b => x:a`
- `"2W:2D,4W:2D"` into `"4W:2D"` applying rule #2 `a:x,b:x => max(a,b):x`
- `"2W:2D,4W:1D"` into `"4W:2D"` applying rule #3 `a:x,b:y => max(a,b):x (if x >= y)`

*Rule #3 is about consecutive time frames (`a < b`) with a more restrictive limit (`x`) applied first. The limits are absolute distances, not frequencies, so (`x > y`) means that `x` is more restrictive than `y`.*

#### Normalizing:

As illustrated in rule #1, only the first of two same-frame thinning levels are applied. I chose to take the one with the least restrictive limit. So a pre-processing to the thinning strategy can be done that reduces the sorted list of pairs *(frame, limit)* to those of each *frame* with the lowest *limit* (I replaced time deltas by numbers):

```
user_input = [(30, 3), (20, 4), (20, 5), (10, 1), (10, 2)]
expected_output = [(10, 1), (20, 4), (30, 3)]
```

This is what I have so far:

```
def normalized(thinning):
    thinning = sorted(thinning)
    deduped = []
    key = None
    for t in thinning:
        if t[0] != key:
            deduped.append(t)
            key = t[0]
    thinning = deduped
    return thinning
```

Is there an obvious way that would lead to a more compact (maybe less procedural) version?

---

<sup>[1]</sup> At the beginning of the process all backups are collected in a to-do list. This list is sorted anti-chronological. Now the thinning strategy is applied time frame for time frame (smallest first): each time frame selects (and removes) timestamps from the to-do list.

Comment: Shouldn't the first rule read `(x, a), (x, b) => (x, min(a, b))`? For the same reason I don't understand rule (3). If you convert `4W:2D,4W:1D` to `4W:2D` you are going to miss a backup every second day. Then later you write that you want to keep the tuple with the smallest `second` which sounds more reasonable in terms of rule (1). Could you clarify this?

Comment: @a_guest I hope [I clarified the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58503746/4). Thanks for commenting on the issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) here:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

[next(v) for _,v in groupby(sorted(user_input), key=itemgetter(0))]
# [(10, 1), (20, 4), (30, 3)]
```

Comment: In the docs of [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) I read that *Generally, the iterable needs to already be sorted on the same key function.* In the given case it's not "the same" key but a stable sort with `key=itemgetter(0)` keeps a sorted list of tuples unchanged.

Comment: This should do as you want @wolf , since sorting will sort by the different elements in the tuple, i.e. first by the first item and then in case of having more than one equal value in another tuple it sort by the second items and so on. Hence then grouping by the first element will work fine, since from what I deduced from the question this is what you want

Comment: Yes, absolutely, it's just a lot to read and to learn :) Thanks for this insightful answer!